# identify tolls within route MapKit in swift

Tags: swift, routes, mapkit

I'm building an app in swift with MapKit to get directions between two coordinates, how to identify if there are tolls on this route? and if there is to identify each of them?

Is there a native way to do this in MapKit?

Can not find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

The `MKDirectionsResponse` object contains an array of `MKRoute` objects. Each `MKRoute` has an `advisoryNotices` property, an array of strings, which, according to a WWDC talk, might have a warning about tolls. The exact format of that notice isn't documented. Those strings are localized, which makes using them even harder. You can present the info to your user, but I don't see how you could make use of it programmatically.